# What is the most efficient way to look up an account name in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written a basic web app in php and MySQL that uses query strings to look up various information. For example: `xxxxxxx.com/?profile=1245`

Very basic, first time developer type of web app.

I want to create different accounts that will each have their own sets of data. I want to differentiate these accounts by using subdomains. For example: `username.xxxxxxxx.com?profile=4527`

I have a catchall set up in my Apache config to divert all subdomains to my main domain and then I can pull that subdomain out using php like so:

`<?php  list( $username ) = explode( ".", $_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ] ); ?>`

**Now, HERE'S MY QUESTION:**

It seems to me (I'm fairly new to all of this) that performing a string based search for every query I need to do on every page is going to be slow and inefficient. For instance, having to look up `SELECT * WHERE username = sampleuser AND profile = 2745`

But is that true? What would be the most efficient way? How do web apps that use subdomains normally handle this sort of thing?

Thank you all so much in advance.

Comment: Well, you could add an index on `username` to your table...

Comment: Thanks paddy. I will do that for sure. But even after doing that, will that remain quick if there are 1000 or more rows (just throwing out a big number)? Everything I've done so far has been on tables with 50 or fewer rows so efficiency wasn't as important.

Comment: Is anything shared between these subdomains in terms of the user data?

Comment: No, no data would be shared amongst subdomains.

Comment: A string index should be very fast even if you have millions of rows.  You could generate a ridiculously large random table and benchmark its performance if in doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How do web apps that use subdomains normally handle this sort of thing?"

Usually each subdomain is mapped in the web engine(apache/IIS) using something like rewrite module, to a specific IP address or a specific root.  So blog.* subdomain might point to the root of the WordPress app.

In your case, that sounds like it wouldn't apply unless you have a different set of pages for each user.  I.e. if they all have a "Account Details" page, and only the data is different, then the only place the subdomain would come into play is with queries, or URLs you generate.

In your case, you have what are conceptually dynamic routes.  Usually you would just query a table to determine what content to serve.  In your case it's not so much content as just data. Sometimes the routes are cached globally in memory using a data structure that is well organized for lookups, in your case lookups via the username that give you back the primary key of the users table.  Then without querying the user's table, you have your filter criteria for data that references that user via a foreign key.  So if the navigate to the "Likes" page, you can "Select * From Likes Where UserKey = $userKeyFromLookup".  You would want to choose an in memory data structure for lookups that allows O(1) lookups.  I.e. constant time lookups.

> It seems to me (I'm fairly new to all of this) that performing a
>   string based search for every query I need to do on every page is
>   going to be slow and inefficient. For instance, having to look up
>   SELECT * WHERE username = sampleuser AND profile = 2745

Is profile ID unique to each user?  If so, then you don't need username in the query.  The profile ID alone would give you a unique response.  If someone visits username.*.* without a profile ID, then first thing you do is grab the profileID then redirect to the same page but now with that parameter in the URL so that all other navigation is done in the context of that profileID.

I agree with Stony though, I think you will find quarks with having dynamic subdomains.  I would put the username in the URL instead.

Comment: Correct... but there is a lot more to do when you want to change your vhost file. And a script which edit your vhost file can be a security problem.

Answer (score 3):

To use a subdomain is not very efficient. When you take a look at SEO. You have many domains and sites that have the same content.

I would prefer a rewrite in your case

```
www.xxxxx.com/username
```

then you can rewrite the username to your script. The problem is that it could be a problem when you create a new subdomain for every user. Its possible, that a user has cached the DNS request and it takes a lot of time to access the site.

The second is you should query the database as little as possible. Save the username or the ID in the session.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
```

Then you can make the query to get the information from your database.

**Edit:** When you need more performance you should have a look at **MongoDB** or use **Memcache** to store/cache things.

Comment: I was going to suggest caching the username in session to(likely as part of authentication), but I am guessing in his case these are pages that other users would browse to.  I'm guessing some sort of social site.  So user Bob might be browsing someOtherUser.blah.com, it would need to lookup someOtherUser, not Bob, because Bob is in the session cache, not someOtherUser.

Comment: Thats correct. But You can make a variable for example 'aktUsername' or 'profileUsername'. But in your case its no problem you can parse it one time at top. But a subdomain for every user is no really good idea

Comment: Correct, AaronLS. 

Only user Bob would be able to edit bob.blah.com but the whole world would be able to view bob.blah.com.

An easy comparison that comes to mind is Tumblr. If you create an account there, you can create content that all gets posted to yourname.tumblr.com  Only you can post stuff, but everyone can view it.

Comment: There are some other possibilities to cache the whole MySQL query or you make a full page cache. And cache the complete site. Then you don't need the requests for a defined time.

Comment: @A.J. Bohac: This shouldn't be a solution for editig :D for editing you need a authentification and this could be saved in a session. Otherwise you have a lot of choas :D

Comment: I can't accept both of your guys' answers, but they were both very helpful. I appreciate your time!